Чекбоксы в Chrome и Firefox
Проблема следующая:
В Мозиле чекбоксы очень маленького размера (как точки), в остальных браузерах стандартного размера. Пытался настроить масштабирование, но безуспешно (запутался в синтаксисе). Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение.

Добавьте в вопрос html разметку и ваши стили, с которыми возникли проблемы. Ну пару скринов для понимания, как это у вас отображается

Без вашего кода даже Ванга бессильна

И операционную систему, так как внешний вид виджетов может зависеть от текущей системной темы

@void, вероятно, он его во флекс засунул...

@Qwertiy вероятно... или фф на ведроиде с ретиной, а остальные на десктопе, когда габариты чекбоксов в пикселях. или какое-то свойство с вендорным префиксом юзнул/не юзнул, кто знает... =) зачем оно ему в конце? чтоб предыдущие стили не перебили(в конец стилей, не верстки)

@puffleeck, ну так все чекбоксы поедут. И вообще не факт, что ему поможет.

@Qwertiy, И вообще не факт, что ему поможет. дык в том то и трабл, при таком кол-ве вводных, вообще мало что тянет на факт. а уж помочь, единственное что щас это и может - дополнение вопроса. ну так все чекбоксы поедут а если там окажется что то типа input{height: 0 !important} то уже никто никуда не едет. хоть с перестановками, хоть без :3

@puffleeck, ну не... Браузеры обычно умеют стили правильно применять. Если размер едет только в FF, но не едет в хроме, то почти наверняка он сунул чекбокс во флекс или грид без обёртки.

@Qwertiy вот пример чекбокса
<label>       <input type='checkbox' name='fl_rules' id='fl_rules' value='1' " . ($fl_rules ? 'checked' : '') . "  onchange='flValueChanged()' />&nbsp;Физическое лицо      </label>

@Qwertiy
<div>       <input type='checkbox' id='fl_rules' value='1' " . ($fl_rules ? 'checked' : '') . " disabled />       <input type='hidden' name='fl_rules' value='" . ($fl_rules ? '1' : '') . "' />       &nbsp;Физическое лицо      </div>

код достался по наследству...

Вот тебе огромный чекбокс (в FF работает - проверил):


input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 0;
}
<input type=checkbox checked>




можно это добавить в ..... и в какое место? в самом начале кода или без разницы?

@Никита, лучше добавить в самый конец. Вот, только такого тега, как <styles> не существует в HTML ;-)

@UModeL, зачем оно ему в конце?

@Никита, можно, но, вероятно, не нужно и бесполезно.

я хотел сказать 
тут файл .php и html выводится через print и echo. И в какое место это прописать... я запутался))))
